# Work with android action bar items with layout and without java class

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to open a dialog (Layout-xml)(**without java class !!**) with one action bar called about.so, this is my `onOptionsItemSelected` codes :

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:

            LocationFound();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void LocationFound() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutdialog);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

then when i want to add the dialog (layout) file in :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutdialog);
```

not allowed to do this.also, i tried this before `Intent` :

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutdialog));
```

the problem is the app cannot find/accept the `aboutdialog`.

So the question is,

How we can do this, when i clicked to `About` button in action bar, it show us the aboutdialog ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `aboutdialog` a Activity or and DialogFragment???

Comment: just a dialog. as i said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an intent to display a dialog. Change your LocationFound() method to this

```
private void LocationFound(View view) {
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: can i set `Locationfound` to `private void` ? i try this but give me an error and i had to use this `private void LocationFound()` and now its work fine like a charm :)

Comment: Sure you can. Sorry I changed it to public. I didn't look at your code properly. I've changed it back to private now.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` it's for moving from one `Activity` to another `Activity`.

> about dialog

It is not `Activity`, so this is why it's not working for you. 
You should use this method instead

```
Dialog.show()
```

It is supposed to be like [that](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog):

```
aboutdialog.show()
```